# Apostrophecms - What is the difference between js files added in different places

Tags: apostrophe-cms, client-side-scripting

Apostrophecms - What is the difference between client side js files added in different places

1. The file which I will add in `my-module -> public -> js -> always.js`
2. The file which I will add in `my-module -> src -> always.js`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apostrophe 2.x (the current major release) has no `src` folders at all, so I'm not sure where that part of the question might come from.

But files in `my-module/public/js` can be pushed via `pushAsset` calls in the module, and if this is done by the module or any of its parent classes then all of the copies of `always.js` that exist, i.e. in the parent class modules or in your module, will be pushed to the browser — in order. And this is helpful for achieving your own overriding and subclassing effects in browser side code.

If you are by some chance looking at the `3.0` branch, that is very much pre-alpha code right now and should not be used for projects. But when `3.0` matures, `src` will replace `public` for most purposes, and it will contain Apostrophe admin UI code meant to be bundled by webpack. This has no bearing on the current stable release of Apostrophe though.

It is possible that you have inherited an Apostrophe project from someone who built their own tooling to compile files in `src/` to targets in `public/js` via `gulp` or `webpack`, but this would be project-level code or independently written Apostrophe modules and not part of Apostrophe itself or any of our current sample projects.

Comment: Yes Tom. I am working on already developed project because of that I can see this `src` folder structure and we are using custom webpack too. Thanks for information.